# Field userRepository in com.bookstore.demo.Services.UserSecurityService required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Right Now I am working in OnlineBook store web application using SpringBoot.I Stared first implementing Spring Security and Some DataBase Roles and Services.
but at First-time compile, I have got some an error.

I am not Sure to add @Repository at UserRepository.

**UserSecurityService.java**

```
package com.bookstore.demo.Services;

import com.bookstore.demo.Repository.UserRepository;
import com.bookstore.demo.domain.security.User;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;


@Service
public class UserSecurityService implements UserDetailsService {

    private static final Logger LOG= LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserSecurityService.class);


    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        User user=userRepository.findByUsername(userName);

        if(null == user)
        {
            LOG.warn("Username {} Not Found",userName);
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Username"+userName+"Not Found");
        }


        return user;
    }


}
```

**UserRepository.java**

```
package com.bookstore.demo.Repository;

import com.bookstore.demo.domain.security.User;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User,Long> {
    User findByUsername(String userName);
    User findByEmail(String eamil);
    List<User> findAll();
}
```

**Pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.bootstore</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>

        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.11</version>
        </dependency>




        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

**DemoApplication.java**

```
package com.bookstore.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication

@EnableJpaRepositories("com.bookstore.demo.Repository")
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**Console Error**

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1\bin\java.exe" -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -noverify -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=64339 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost -Dspring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain -Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.5\lib\idea_rt.jar=64340:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.5\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\ujash\OneDrive\BootStore_Boot\target\classes;C:\Users\ujash\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-web\2.0.3.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-web-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ujash\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\2.0.3.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ujash\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\2.0.3.RELEASE\spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ujash\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\2.0.3.RELEASE\spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ujash\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\2.0.3.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-logging-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ujash\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.2.3\logback-classic-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\ujash\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.2.3\logback-core-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\ujash\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.10.0\log4j-to-slf4j-2.10.0.jar;C:\Users\ujash\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.10.0\log4j-api-2.10.0.jar;C:\Users\ujash\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.25\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.25.jar;C:\Users\ujash\.m2\repository\javax\annotation\javax.annotation-api\1.3.2\javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar;C:\Users\ujash\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.19\snakeyaml-1.19.jar;C:\Users\ujash\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-json\2.0.3.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-json-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ujash\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.9.6\jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar;C:\Users\ujash\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.9.0\jackson-annotations-2.9.0.jar;C:\Users\ujash\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.9.6\jackson-core-2.9.6.jar;C:\Users\ujash\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.9.6\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.9.6.jar;C:\Users\ujash\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.9.6\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.9.6.jar;C:\Users\ujash\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.9.6\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.9.6.jar;C:\Users\ujash\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-tomcat\2.0.3.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ujash\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-core\8.5.31\tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar;C:\Users\ujash\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-el\8.5.31\tomcat-embed-el-8.5.31.jar;C:\Users\ujash\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-websocket\8.5.31\tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.31.jar;C:\Users\ujash\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\validator\hibernate-validator\6.0.10.Final\hibernate-validator-6.0.10.Final.jar;C:\Users\ujash\.m2\repository\javax\validation\validation-api\2.0.1.Final\validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\ujash\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.3.2.Final\jboss-logging-3.3.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\ujash\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.3.4\classmate-1.3.4.jar;C:\Users\ujash\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\5.0.7.RELEASE\spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ujash\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\5.0.7.RELEASE\spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ujash\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\5.0.7.RELEASE\spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ujash\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\5.0.7.RELEASE\spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ujash\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\5.0.7.RELEASE\spring-expression-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ujash\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa\2.0.3.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ujash\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-aop\2.0.3.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-aop-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ujash\.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.8.13\aspectjweaver-1.8.13.jar;C:\Users\ujash\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\5.2.17.Final\hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar;C:\Users\ujash\.m2\repository\org\javassist\javassist\3.22.0-GA\javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar;C:\Users\ujash\.m2\repository\antlr\antlr\2.7.7\antlr-2.7.7.jar;C:\Users\ujash\.m2\repository\org\jboss\jandex\2.0.3.Final\jandex-2.0.3.Final.jar;C:\Users\ujash\.m2\repository\dom4j\dom4j\1.6.1\dom4j-1.6.1.jar;C:\Users\ujash\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\common\hibernate-commons-annotations\5.0.1.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\ujash\.m2\repository\javax\transaction\javax.transaction-api\1.2\javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar;C:\Users\ujash\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-jpa\2.0.8.RELEASE\spring-data-jpa-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ujash\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-commons\2.0.8.RELEASE\spring-data-commons-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ujash\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-orm\5.0.7.RELEASE\spring-orm-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ujash\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\5.0.7.RELEASE\spring-tx-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ujash\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.25\slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar;C:\Users\ujash\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aspects\5.0.7.RELEASE\spring-aspects-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ujash\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-jdbc\2.0.3.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-jdbc-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ujash\.m2\repository\com\zaxxer\HikariCP\2.7.9\HikariCP-2.7.9.jar;C:\Users\ujash\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\5.0.7.RELEASE\spring-jdbc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ujash\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-security\2.0.3.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-security-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ujash\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\5.0.7.RELEASE\spring-aop-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ujash\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-config\5.0.6.RELEASE\spring-security-config-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ujash\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-web\5.0.6.RELEASE\spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ujash\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-core\5.0.6.RELEASE\spring-security-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ujash\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\5.0.7.RELEASE\spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ujash\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\5.0.7.RELEASE\spring-jcl-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ujash\.m2\repository\mysql\mysql-connector-java\8.0.11\mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar;C:\Users\ujash\.m2\repository\com\google\protobuf\protobuf-java\2.6.0\protobuf-java-2.6.0.jar;C:\Users\ujash\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\javax\persistence\hibernate-jpa-2.1-api\1.0.2.Final\hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.2.Final.jar com.bookstore.demo.DemoApplication

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.3.RELEASE)

2018-08-03 23:12:24.542  INFO 12696 --- [           main] com.bookstore.demo.DemoApplication       : Starting DemoApplication on DESKTOP-D0AQG89 with PID 12696 (C:\Users\ujash\OneDrive\BootStore_Boot\target\classes started by ujash in C:\Users\ujash\OneDrive\BootStore_Boot)
2018-08-03 23:12:24.558  INFO 12696 --- [           main] com.bookstore.demo.DemoApplication       : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-08-03 23:12:26.526  INFO 12696 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@38089a5a: startup date [Fri Aug 03 23:12:25 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1 (file:/C:/Users/ujash/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/5.0.7.RELEASE/spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
2018-08-03 23:12:43.806  INFO 12696 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2018-08-03 23:12:44.056  INFO 12696 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2018-08-03 23:12:44.056  INFO 12696 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.31
2018-08-03 23:12:44.088  INFO 12696 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\ujash\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\ujash\AppData\Roaming\npm;.]
2018-08-03 23:12:44.697  INFO 12696 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-08-03 23:12:44.697  INFO 12696 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 19077 ms
2018-08-03 23:12:45.197  INFO 12696 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-08-03 23:12:45.197  INFO 12696 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2018-08-03 23:12:45.197  INFO 12696 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2018-08-03 23:12:45.197  INFO 12696 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2018-08-03 23:12:45.197  INFO 12696 --- [ost-startStop-1] .s.DelegatingFilterProxyRegistrationBean : Mapping filter: 'springSecurityFilterChain' to: [/*]
2018-08-03 23:12:45.197  INFO 12696 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
2018-08-03 23:12:45.916  WARN 12696 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userSecurity'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userSecurityService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#44b29496' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#44b29496': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
2018-08-03 23:12:45.916  INFO 12696 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2018-08-03 23:12:46.369  INFO 12696 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-08-03 23:12:46.728 ERROR 12696 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field userRepository in com.bookstore.demo.Services.UserSecurityService required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: See the below link: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41170661/spring-data-jpa-consider-defining-a-bean-named-entitymanagerfactory-in-your)

Comment: I tried all thinks that menstion in ans