# Spring Boot: Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am receiving the following error when trying to start up my Spring Boot application:

Note: This error only occurs when I put the `@Autowired` annotation over the `IDeviceRepository iDeviceRepository;` in the `DeviceDao.java` class

I have yet to get the `DeviceDao.java` to persist to the database - but the entities are being created

```
> *************************** 
> APPLICATION FAILED TO START
> ***************************
> 
> Description: 
> Field iDeviceRepository in com.abc.dao.DeviceDao required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found. 
> Action:
> Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.
```

This is directory structure of the project:

```
├───src
│   ├───main
│   │   ├───java
│   │   │   └───com
│   │   │       └───abc
│   │   │           ├───controller
│   │   │           ├───dao
│   │   │           │   └───repositories
│   │   │           ├───init
│   │   │           ├───model
│   │   │           ├───service
│   │   │           └───util
│   │   │               ├───common
│   │   │               ├───enums
│   │   │               ├───exceptions
│   │   │               └───interfaces
│   │   └───resources
│   │       ├───static
│   │       │   ├───css
│   │       │   ├───fonts
│   │       │   ├───img
│   │       │   └───js
│   │       └───templates
```

**com.abc.init.Application.java**

```
package com.abc.init;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.abc.dao.repositories")
@EntityScan(basePackages = { "com.abc.model" })
@ComponentScan(basePackages={ "com.abc.controller", "com.abc.service", "com.abc.dao" })
public class Application
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

**com.abc.controller.RegisterController.java**

```
package com.abc.controller;

@Controller
public class RegisterController
{
    @Autowired
    RegisterServiceImpl registerService;

    @GetMapping("/register")
    public String registerForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("device", new Device());
        return "registerDevice";
    }

    @PostMapping("/register")
    public String registerSubmit(@ModelAttribute Device device) {
        registerService.registerDevice(device)
        return "registerDeviceSuccess";
    }
}
```

**com.abc.service.RegisterServiceImpl.java**

```
package com.abc.service;

@Service
public class RegisterServiceImpl implements IRegisterService
{
    @Autowired
    DeviceDao devDao;

    public boolean registerDevice (Device device) {
        devDao.saveDevice(device);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**com.abc.util.interfaces.IRegisterService**

```
package com.abc.util.interfaces;

public interface IRegisterService
{
    public boolean registerDevice(Device device);
}
```

**com.abc.dao.DeviceDao.java**

```
package com.abc.dao;

@Repository
public class DeviceDao 
{
    @Autowired
    IDeviceRepository iDeviceRepository;

    public Device saveDevice(Device device) {
        return iDeviceRepository.save(device);
    }
}
```

**com.abc.dao.repositories.IDeviceRepository.java**

```
package com.abc.dao.repositories;

@Repository
public interface IDeviceRepository extends CrudRepository<Device, Long> {}
```

**application.properties**

```
# Exposed HTTP Port
server.port = 8090

# Database Configuration Parameters
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb
spring.datasource.username=mydbadmin
spring.datasource.password=mydbpassword
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver

# Hibernate Configurations
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=false

# Display SQL Commands in Terminal
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

**Stack Trace:**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'registerController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'registerService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'registerServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'devDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'deviceDao': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'iDeviceRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'IDeviceRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#36dce7ed' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#36dce7ed': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'registerServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'devDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'deviceDao': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'iDeviceRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'IDeviceRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#36dce7ed' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#36dce7ed': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'deviceDao': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'iDeviceRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'IDeviceRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#36dce7ed' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#36dce7ed': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'IDeviceRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#36dce7ed' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#36dce7ed': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#36dce7ed': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
```

Can anyone please advise?

Comment: Remove `@EnableJpaRepositories, @EntityScan, @ComponentScan` annotations and check if this exception appears. Springboot automaticly makes a lot of configurations and those annotations can has incorrect impact on it. Besides you should user `@Service` annotation on classes which do some business logic (like RegisterServiceImpl  in your case). `@Repository` annotation is dedicated for classes responsible for fetching data from diffrent sources.

Comment: Unfortunatley it doesnt work - I think I need to explicitly use the 3 annotations due to the structure of the project. I've added the stack trace

Comment: Can you also post `application.properties` file? Might be helpful.

Comment: @KamilW. ServiceImpl classes should have `@Service` instead of `@Repository` ?

Comment: Added application.properties

Comment: Please take a look at this article: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bean-annotations

Comment: Put your `Application` in `com.abc` instead of `com.abc.init`. Remove all the annotations but `@SpringBootApplication`.

Comment: @M. Deinum when I move application to com.abc and remove annotations I get the following error:
`Description:
Field emailService in com.abc.controller.RegisterController required a bean of type 'com.abc.service.EmailServiceImpl' that could not be found.
Action:
Consider defining a bean of type 'com.abc.service.EmailServiceImpl' in your configuration.`

Comment: @AK47 can you remove DeviceDao repository as you already have IDeviceRepository with extending Curd or JPA, it has all crud methods so no need to define crud operations in it..if you need any custom then you can define same in your repository interface.

Comment: Try to use IRegisterService in RegisterController class instead of RegisterServiceImpl. Like this:  @Autowired
    IRegisterService registerService;

Comment: If you are using maven, then
(1). Delete the repositories in .m2 
(2). Then recompile project and try build again. 
[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51314877/10099219)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In spring-boot, you don't need to annotate your repository class with the repository annotation.

```
@Repository
```

You just need to extend JPARepository on your interface and Spring-boot will take care of the rest. 
For Example:

```
public interface YourRepository extends JpaRepository<YourDomain, Serializable> {

    YourDomain findBysomeparameter(Long parameter);

}
```

And you don't need to add these annotations:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EntityScan
@ComponentScan
```

Spring-boot does that automatically unless you're doing some configuration.

I hope this will help.

Comment: When I updated the interface to `public interface IDeviceRepository extends JpaRepository<Device, Long> {}` and remove the `@Repository` annotation it still throws the same error. As for the annotations - see my last comment on the question - the annotations are required currently because of the structure of the project, but even when moving the `Application.java` class to `com.abc` package and removing the annotation it's still failing to build

Comment: Yes, the same issue I am observing. Is there any solution ?.

Comment: Stop coping the same solution without testing

Comment: @fsalazar_sch can you share the reference because this code is from my project that I've used.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue when I started learning Spring-Boot some months back. I am not sure whether Spring takes directory structure seriously. I had similar directory structure as @Pawan. All you have to do is move your repository folder one level up i.e. move it into parent **abc** folder. Annotate your DeviceDao class with @Service. Finally update the repository path in **@EnableJpaRepository**. This worked for me. Hope this help.